# why we have to use exact text between labels at spring mvc in spite of writing th:text at thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am beginner at thymeleaf that's why this question might be very basic for you.

Why we have to write exact text between Label dags despite we are using th:text at label at SpringMVC ?

I meant Sender

When I change mgInput.sender the text in the label changes, but when I change the text "Sender" between label tags. Label is not changed.So why Sender or Sender text is necessary between label tags.

I hope I was clear for the question.

Regards
Alper

Comment: can you add a code example?

Answer (score 0):

This is so you can give the HTML file to a UI designer and they can work independently.  The text between the label tags will be shown if you open up the HTML document when it's not running on a container or server.

This is extremely helpful because a UI designer can work on the HTML file without having any direct knowledge of Tomcat or some application server, or any real environment setup.

For example, open this up in a browser without running it in Tomcat/Spring and you'll see "Sender".

```
<span th:text="${mgInput.sender}">Sender</span>
```

In fact, you can even email the files to someone and they can view it with the `Sender` text.  This is not possible with some other templating frameworks.